Paper rejected as out-of-scope after submitting a minor revision
I sent my paper to a journal. The editor sent it for reviewing. I then received an email from the editor to congratulate me. I had have to revise the paper according to the minor corrections recommended by the reviewers. I did as requested and sent the modified paper to the editor.
I was surprised by reply from the editor that "your paper is not within the scope of the journal". Why didn't the editor reject the paper before sending it to reviewers, avoiding wasted time? Can I sue him for the this mistake that made me wait over a month? What do I have to do?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105065/what-should-i-do-when-my-accepted-paper-is-subsequently-rejected Does this answer your question?

Obviously, the editor did not do the editor's job well and you are rightfully upset. You can complain about the editor to the owners of the journal. For example, Elsevier has a complaint site. If the journal is run by a small entity, then it might take quite a bit of effort to find out even how to complain. But, in a case like this, the editor's judgement usually, but not always prevails.
Whether you can take legal steps is a different question. First, you need to have a tort, i.e. have suffered by someone violating your legal rights, or have had a broken contract that resulted in damages. The first seems impossible, and the second is at best debatable. One could argue that the editor did you a favor by preventing your article to be published in an unsuitable journal. Thus, showing damages would not be easy. Whether there is an enforceable contract also seems to be dubious.
Finally, even in the unlikely case that you and the editor are residing legally in the same jurisdiction, pressing a case would pose all sorts of difficulties. In addition, the other side is likely to have lawyers on retainer, whereas you would need to hire one. So, legal action has at best dubious chances and in any case, is difficult.

You answered and hit the mark. Thank you.

Not to say how badly suing a journal would look on you, even if you're (mostly) right.

Thank you for this advice
